# Problem with mysql workbench in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench

My workbench was working just fine before this update. Once I installed the new version I noticed that the management tab was empty and also the server options showed up empty. Initially I thought problem was with workbench. So I re-installed entire mysql as well as workbench and it did not help. On searching online and following steps I realized that ssl access is not enabled. Also ubuntu 15.04 update log mentions this that 'export cipher suites have been disabled'. In mysql I ran this then to check :

```
show variables like '%ssl%'
-> ;
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| have_openssl  | DISABLED |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED |
| ssl_ca        |          |
| ssl_capath    |          |
| ssl_cert      |          |
| ssl_cipher    |          |
| ssl_crl       |          |
| ssl_crlpath   |          |
| ssl_key       |          |
+---------------+----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I believe that not having SSL is preventing me from making use of local management in workbench to import/export database etc. How do I enable this? Is there any alternative way to get back my workbench management tools?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a full MySQL Workbench log file (execute MySQL Workbench with `--log-level=debug3` command line arg)? I know this shoud be posted as comment, but my reputation not allow me fro that.